# How to accept .psd, .avi, .mov files in nestjs file interceptor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, nestjs

I am trying to accept multiple images in my request body, The files I am having problems are .mov, .psd, .avi.

This is my current code snippet

```
@UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('upload_image', 10))
  async uploadImage(
    @UploadedFiles(
      new ParseFilePipe({
        validators: [
          new FileTypeValidator({
            fileType: '.(png|jpeg|jpg|pdf|gif|svg|mp4|psd|bmp|mov|avi)',
          }),
          new MaxFileSizeValidator({ maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 4 }),
        ],
      }),
    )
    files,
    @Body() body: UploadFileDto,
    @Req() req,
    @Res() res,
  ) {
// Some service logic
}
```

Iam getting the below response after selecting .avi , .mov, .psd files

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": "Validation failed (expected type is .(png|jpeg|jpg|pdf|gif|svg|mp4|psd|bmp|mov|avi))",
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

It accepts file for evry other format other than the formats mentioned above.

Comment: _"The files I am having problems are"_ What problems, you haven't stated what problems you are having. What are the symptoms? What debugging have you done to try and get it to work?

Comment: I have edited the Question with the necessary information

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding mimeType as well. May be its throwing as mimeType is not mentioned.
Refer this piece of code `fileType: '^.*.(mov|quicktime|photoshop)$',`